# Why is 'fetch' returning undefined when i try to fetch a channel? | discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to fetch all the channels in a discord server then check each message if a specific user has written them. However, it keeps causing an error whenever I'm attempting to fetch a channel.

```
                message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
                    channel.messages.fetch().then(messages => {
                        if(messages.author.id == member.id) {
                            messages.forEach(msg => console.log(msg.content));
                        }
                    });
                  });
```

Error:

```
                        channel.messages.fetch().then(messages => {
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')
```

member is already defined and have used it before, just not included in the code snippet.

Comment: Because it's fetching other than text channels too, those don't have the `messages` property, be careful to exclude them. Take a look at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel!

Comment: You can add a type gaurd by doing `if (!channel.isText()) return` at the top of your forEach callback

Comment: That works, thanks guys :) and also, `messages.author.id` is undefined, well the `id` is there another way to grab that message author id?

Comment: It's `<Message>.author.id`, not `<MessageManager>.author.id`, verify the condition in your `forEach` loop.

Comment: explain a bit more? i don't quiet understand @Leau

Comment: nevermind, i got it thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you used the `forEach()` function for any channel on the server,

But there is a channels that doesn't has the `messages` property (eg. `GUILD_VOICE`).
And that's why you got this error.
What you can do is filter the channels to only `GUILD_TEXT`.

Code Example:

```js
    message.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === "GUILD_TEXT").forEach((ch) => {
        // do here your stuff
    })
```